# Images on BlackBerry Web Browser loading sporadically 

Tags: image, blackberry, xhtml, amazon-ec2

I have several standard XHTML image tags on a valid XHTML 1.0 STRICT html page.

`<img src="/_assets/img/icon-payroll.png" alt="" />`

For some reason on blackberry phones the images will sometimes show and sometimes not. It's never the same images, and it appears to be completely random in deciding which one will show. Just hitting refresh will cause the same image to load or not display at random. The page in question has a total of 7 *png* images. Sometimes only 1 or 2 will show, occasionally all 7 will show.

The test server is an Amazon EC 2 instance.

This issue does not appear on the iPhone, iPod touch, iPad, Andriod, Safari (for desktop), Firefox, Chrome, Opera, or Internet Explorer. It appears to only be an issue with Blackberry phones.

**[EDIT]**

The issue appears to be on all blackberry phones and on all networks.

Here is a device list of the current Blackberrys with this issue:

- BB Curve 8530 (*Sprint*)    OS:  v5.0.0.654
- BB Torch 9800 (*AT&T*)    OS:  v6.0.0.246
- BB Tour  9630   (*Verizon*) OS:  v5.0.0.975

Comment: This look like a network problem (SPRINT + this model of device) in this case. There seems to be a kind of timeout with some resources.

Comment: Normally I would agree but I just tested on two other models and on two other networks. Same issue... see my edited question above to see the exact device make/model/network.

Comment: Do you have a test page, so we can test too.

Comment: Mike I'll build one for you guys. I can't link to the actual app for many reasons, but I'll get a sample up by tomorrow morning at the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced resource load failure based on connection type.
Some default connections would timeout -- specifically on an 9700 AT&T phone -- yet the WAP connection would load the images just fine, then on a Sprint 8520, the WAP connection would occasionally timeout, yet the default connection would perform as expected.
If you can, try different connection types -- you may also experience speed gains by varying the connection type by vendor preference (which seems to be what I have found -- haven't explored the possibility completely, yet).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Apparently though it is indiscriminate of whether I am on a wifi connection on the sprint network.